# Atualizar Versão de Aplicativo Automaticamente - Cordova

Tags: angular, apache-cordova, npm, linha-de-comando, bat

O script abaixo grava a versão em um `txt`, porém está dando algum erro que no arquivo `txt` aparece como :

> "ECHO está desativado".

```
@ECHO OFF

CALL npm version > version

SET /p ver=<version
DEL version
SET ver=%ver:{ 'aplicat-resta': '='%
SET ver=%ver:~1,-2%

CALL cordova-set-version -v %ver%

ECHO %ver% > ..\..\AplicatResta\Resta\version_app.txt

ECHO on
```

Alguém consegue saber o que exatamente está ocorrendo esse erro?  Ou alguma forma de atualizar a versão automaticamente?

OBS.: quando chamo `cordova-set-version`, o mesmo não é reconhecido, porém mesmo se eu comentá-lo ainda assim grava `"ECHO está desativado"` no `txt`.

Answer (score 0):

> Alguém consegue saber o que exatamente está ocorrendo esse erro? <strike>Ou alguma forma de atualizar a versão automaticamente</strike>?

- **1.** Redireciona todas as linhas da saída do comando `CALL npm version` para arquivo `version`:

```
CALL npm version > version 
:: salva todas as linhas da saída de comando no arquivo version
```

- **2.** Define a variável `set ver={` (apenas a primeira linha do comando redirecionado)

```
SET /p ver=<version 
:: set /p vai assumir/definir sempre a primeira linha 
:: do arquivo redirecionado, no seu caso version ==> "{"
```

- **3.** Define a variável `ver` com um(a) substring/substituição que é inexistente

```
SET /p ver=<version 
            ↳ é o mesmo que: SET /p ver={ 

SET ver=%ver:{ 'aplicat-resta': '='%
SET ver=%ver:{ 'aplicat-resta': '='%
:: o valor atribuido na variável ver não comporta/não executa 
:: a substituição, então a variável mantém seu valor atual ver={
```

- **4.** Remove a variável `ver` com o comando `SET ver=`

```
SET ver=%ver:~1,-2% 
              ↳  ↳ é o mesmo que: SET ver= 
SET ver=%ver:~1,-2%
:: não existe um index 1 na sua variável definida como {, 
:: também não há como suprimir os ultimos 2 dígitos da várivel de forma que 
:: possa obedecer a substring: variável=(variável: valor do (index 1), até o (index total -2))
:: assim, vai resultar num valor nulo, tornando a execução na remoção da sua variável: SET ver=
```

- **5.**  Uma edição que explique o que deseja passar como ver apontaria para uma solução mais precisa

```
CALL cordova-set-version -v %ver% 
CALL cordova-set-version -v %ver%
              ↳ é o mesmo que: Call cordova-set-version -v 
:: como a variável foi removida, esse comando é executado com um argumento
:: a menos, onde não há a variável nem valores em/para ver definidos em %ver%
```

- **6.** Comando `echo` vai informar o seu estado definido por `on` ou `off` quando executado e/ou redirecionando na saída para o arquivo apontado:

```
ECHO %ver% > ..\..\AplicatResta\Resta\version_app.txt
ECHO %ver% > ..\..\AplicatResta\Resta\version_app.txt
  ↳       ↳ é o mesmo que: ECHO > ..\..\AplicatResta\Resta\version_app.txt

:: como a variável %ver% foi removida nas execuções anteriores, o interpretador 
:: de comandos (cmd.exe) não tem como passar argumento %ver% para o comando ECHO
:: resultando como saída do ECHO [%string nenhuma%] + [redirecionamento de sáida] [arquivo.txt],
:: apenas o status atual do comando ECHO, e como foi definido na primeira linha do seu arquivo bat
:: (@echo off), é exatamente isto que tens recebes no arquivo apontado para redirecionamendo do echo
```

---

- Para fins de comprovação do comportamento `echo`

```
:: define echo off
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

:: apaga existindo ou não o arquivo .\status.txt 
2>nul del .\status.txt

:: remove definida ou não a variável ver
set "ver="

:: teste de 'echo variável que não existe' fazendo retornar status definido `off`
ECHO %ver% >status.txt

:: lista conteúdo atual do arquivo .\status.txt
@type status.txt

:: define echo on
@echo on

:: teste de 'echo variável que não existe' fazendo retornar status definido `on`
@ECHO %ver% >status.txt

:: lista conteúdo atual do arquivo .\status.txt
@type status.txt
```

- Outputs/saídas:

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is on.
```

---

Para saber mais sobre o comando `Echo` consulte:

- **[`echo` /MS-Doc's](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)**
- **[`echo /?` /ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)** <sup>****English***</sup>